# is there any recommended requirements for running a full node for mining?

Tags: cryptocurrency, wavesplatform

we moved our full node to digitalocean servers. It's not so powerful as it was before.

We are helding about 100K waves but unfortunately the node cant mine blocks efficient since we moved it to this server. We wonder if there is a relation between cpu/memory power and mining.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. But how could there /not/ be a relation? You need computing power to do computing, whatever the application, and especially compute-intensive stuff. I would speak to whoever sized your digitalocean server and get them to reconsider the resources they asked for. (And what sort of difference in cpu and memory are we talking about?)

Comment: P.S. and are you sure the server has been configured and tuned in the same way as your previous one? You don't say what operating system you are running.

Answer (score 2):

For a waves node, 4GB is mostly enough, but 8GB is what I use to run a waves node.
Another important point is SSD, a blockchain is a lot of writing to the disk. So if you got a bad drive/slow write speed you might also suffer a penalty.

Besides the "basic" requirements, increasing ram to for example 32GB won't give you a higher chance on blocks. This is because Waves is not a proof-of-work(Leased Proof of Stake). Getting more leases does tho.

I have 2 vps'en myself. Both same amount of ram, but less IO throughput, which causes 1 vps to sync at double speed from the other vps.